# Can I read from a TextBox in Silverlight Accordion

Tags: silverlight

I have an accordion and I want to put a textbox and a button in the accordionitem so that when the button is clicked, I can read the value entered in the textbox. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have the Accordion namespace included to have access to the control, then:

```
<toolkit:Accordion>
    <toolkit:AccordionItem>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" />
        <Button x:Name="buttonButton" Click="buttonButton_Click" />
    </toolkit:AccordionItem>
</toolkit:Accordion>
```

Then (assuming you're in C#):

```
private void buttonButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string value = textBox.Text;
}
```

Where 'value' is whatever text was entered in the text box.